# im trying to get the index of a character using only the charAt and length methods for strings

Tags: java, string, string-length, charat

im trying to get the index of a character using only the charAt and length methods for strings. this is what the question asks :Declare a public method called indexOf that takes a character parameter and returns the index in the stored string of the first occurrence of that character or -1 if the character is not found.
this is what i did.

```
public int indexOf(char c){
    for(i=0; i <string.length - 1; i++){
    if(string.charAt(c) == string.charAt(i)){
    return i;
    else {
    return -1;
    }
    }
```

Comment: what is your question? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please don't just dump your homework here. Show what you've tried and explain any specific problems you've encountered.

Comment: public int indexOf(char c) {
  for(int a =0; a<s.length();a++){
   a = s.charAt(a);
   if(s.charAt(c) == a){
    return a;
   }
   else{
    return -1;
   }
  }
  return 0;

Comment: not sure how else to show this code in the block form. not sure how to use this site

Comment: Use [edit] option (placed below your question) to add code example. Don't post it in comment since it looses its formatting and becomes unreadable.

Answer (score 3):

You need a `for` loop from `0` to `length()-1`, and test the value equality of `charAt(index)` with the given character.

Comment: ++ for no-code answer of homework question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int indexOf(String word, char c) {
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (word.charAt(i) == c){
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Explanation provided by : @Abbé Résina.